# Adaptive UI interface in iOS 8 through iphone 5 to iphone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, adaptive-ui

I have created an app which runs on different devices, but when i set everything in interface builder, it looks like despite of constraints, the labels or buttons are positioned differently in different devices in the simulator.
i.e.: i have an interface i designed, i use it as background image view in the interface builder, using iphone 5 size as reference. in this image i designed a field, when i put a label in it, it looks in different position in the simulated iphone 5 and iphone 6, even though it has been constrained in the same way.
what am i doing wrong?
thx so much for your help!!!

ps: i am assuming the image view sizes are proportional between iphone 5 and 6, so they should naturally have the same aspect ratio hence will the label constraints

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to explain setting constraints between different view sizes with Autolayout is to watch how it's done. Here's an [excellent video from Stanford University's CS193P iOS development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pv1EHGEf884#t=32m0s) course explaining how it works.

[Here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/) you'll find resources for the course. You can also download full lectures from iTunesU.

Comment: As far as i see, i'm having issues just with Interface Builder itself, coz when i start laying out from iPhone6, everything looks fine when i run the simulator even in iphone5. doing viceversa, everything is messed up....that's quite strange i guess...

Answer (score 0):

I've watched both the Stanford video and this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSV6VcGdXPc

Both were helpful, but I found the video by Mitchell Hudson to be much more useful.